# Reshape 4d numpy array to 2d array while preserving array locations

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 4 dimensional numpy array of shape `(N, N, Q, Q)`. So given a row and column index `(i, j)`, `mat[i,j]` is a `QxQ` matrix.  I want to reshape this array to shape `(N*Q, N*Q)` such that

```
array([[[[ 0,  1],
         [ 2,  3]],

        [[ 4,  5],
         [ 6,  7]]],


       [[[ 8,  9],
         [10, 11]],

        [[12, 13],
         [14, 15]]]])
```

goes to

```
array([[  0.,   1.,   4.,   5.],
       [  2.,   3.,   6.,   7.],
       [  8.,   9.,  12.,  13.],
       [ 10.,  11.,  14.,  15.]])
```

You can see that `mat[0,0]` goes to `new_mat[0:2, 0:2]`.  Currently `mat.reshape(N*Q, N*Q)` takes `mat[0,0]` to `new_mat[0:4, 0]` (which is what I do not want).  How can I use reshape or rollaxis or something similar to reshape this array?  I eventually want to plot it with `imshow`, am currently stuck.  I figure it's easy to do, I just haven't yet figured it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out. `np.swapaxes(1, 2)` was the missing piece I needed.

The answer is just to do `mat.swapaxes(1, 2).reshape(N*Q, N*Q)`.

Feel foolish for posting without attempting to figure it out myself for too long, but I'll leave it up so others can benefit from it.